# Does Carpet Tile require use of a Plastic carpet protector?

Tags: flooring, carpet

I use a plastic chair protector with my office chair. Right now its sitting in the middle of the room and looks ugly. In renovation, we are thinking of getting "carpet tile". Would getting carpet tile, reduce the need for using a plastic protector, or are they still required?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are never **required** - just a question of where you want the wear to be borne (and if doing it right, what type of wheels you put on the chair - hard floor or protector being a hard surface should use different wheels than direct-on-carpet, normally.)

Comment: I have a more costly grade of wool carpet, after 25 years this question made me look at it; no sign of wear or other deterioration. There have been about 4 different chairs on it.

Comment: well I am looking for a type of carpet that withstands furniture and office chairs, I read carpet tile is used in offices and withstands all that , compared to regular, soft residential carpet

Comment: I gave points anyway, feel free to add comments, or add/edits in answer, thanks